# Use Python to replace a string in a HTML table

Tags: python, xml, replace

My Python program is having a hard time with the symbol &#10004 and I want to replace it with the word "PASS".

This is what my table looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id = "neutral" align="center">&#1004</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I am trying to replace that string like this:

```
fileString = ""

for elem in root.iter():
  if elem.tag == 'table':
    for row in elem.findall('tr'):
      for column in row.findall('td'):
        fileString = fileString.text.replace('&#10004','PASS')
```

I also tried:

```
for elem in root.findall('td'):
  if elem.text == "&#10004" in elem.text:
    elem.string = 'Pass'
```

But when I try and run, I get an xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: Not well-formed (invalid token): Line 43, column 45.

FYI, fileSting is not empty, the XML file is being fed in through a separate function, I am not having any issues there.

I have a feeling I am either really close or really far off.

Comment: How do you set `root`?

Comment: @Don root = file.getroot()

Comment: @Echo_ghost Try it with something more simple, e.g. replace an `a` by `b`, this will make the code not as confusing

Comment: @monamona I am sorry, I am not sure what you mean by replace 'a' by 'b'

Comment: You want to replace &#10004 by PASS. Replace &#10004 by a and PASS by b, this will make the code and the errormessages easlier to understand

Comment: It is likely not your code that has the problem but there is some string or entity in the xml/html that is not parseable and needs to be escaped.

Comment: @blues Thas is the issues I am having. It is telling me that &#1004 is an invalid token. I just want to see if it is possible for me to replace it with just some simple text like "Pass" satisfy the error. I dont need or want that &#1004 (FYI that is a check mark symbol )

Comment: try the `encoding='utf-8'` parameter when initializing the xml structure. or replacing the entity with regular string replacemment ahead of reading it into an xml tree.